# Additivity & one-point Continuity of $f \in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ imply there is $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(\alpha x) = \alpha x$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I am looking for hints/help concerning a proposition I found self-studying Carothers:

> Suppose that $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ satisfies $f(x+y) = f(x)+f(y)$ for every $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$. If $f$ is continuous at some point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$, prove that there is some constant
>   $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(\alpha x) = \alpha x$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

My initial ideas to prove the result move along the following lines.

1. Notice by additivity that $f(0) = 0$.
2. Take the point $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is continuous by assumption.
3. Obtain that if $|x_0| > \delta_\varepsilon$, then $|f(x_0)|<\varepsilon$
4. Take a $\varepsilon >0$ large enough to get a $\delta_{\varepsilon}>0$ such that $|x_0|<\delta_{\varepsilon}$
5. etc...

The final idea is to construct $\alpha$ as the result of $\tan \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the $x$-axis, and the line that passes through $x_0$ from the origin.

*Does this all make sense?*

Thank you for your time.

Comment: (3) is strange. What is $\epsilon$? What are you comparing $\delta$ to $x_0$? Continuity is about points $x'$ with $|x_0-x'|<\delta$ then...

Comment: I think you want to prove that there is some constant $\alpha$ such that $f(x) = \alpha x$ for all $x$. To find such a constant, you might use the slope as described, or just set $\alpha = f(1)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews : the question states $f(\alpha x) = \alpha x$, I'm suggesting to correct it to $f(x) = \alpha x$.

Comment: Oh, I see, I read the question and corrected in my brain :) @JoelCohen

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: In (3), I was using the continuity of $x_0$ and $0$ as the other point. Thus, if $|x_0 - 0| < \delta$, then $|f(x_0) - f(0)| < \varepsilon$.

Comment: Well, that's true, but that doesn't help you, because $x_0$ could be $1,000,000$, so there's no reason to expect $|x_0-0|<\delta.$ @Kolmin

Comment: @JoelCohen: Forgive my math naivete, but why can we proceed with proving $f(x) = \alpha x$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: That's why I proceeded with step (4), that honestly looked rather slippery to me.

Comment: His point is that you've misstated the problem (or the problem was misstated to you.) It is not true that $f(\alpha x)=\alpha x$ necessarily, since that just means that $f(x)=x$. It is true that $f(x)=\alpha x$ for some $\alpha$.

Comment: Oh, ok I see. Yeah, it is misstated in the title, because I did not want to make it longer than what already was (in the body of the question is correct). :)

Comment: @Kolmin : sorry my comment was not clear, I was just pointing a small typo :) Yes proving $f(x) = \alpha x$ is not directly obvious. To do that, start with $x$ and integer, then extend it to rational numbers, and then to any real number using continuity.

Comment: The question as (mis)stated has the trivial solution $\alpha = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $f(x)=f(x+x_0-x_1)-f(x_0-x_1)$. Use that to show that $f(x)$ is continuous at any $x_1$ if it is continuous at $x_0$.

Next, let $\alpha = f(1)$ and show that $f(x)=f(1)x$ first for $x$ an integer, then $x$ a rational, and then, by continuity, all the reals.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Actually I had already found here on math.stack an answer to the specific problem you are referring to (in both cases). But, my fault, I could not really see how this help to construct the $\alpha$ in the proof, unless we proceed by contradiction (and even in that case, I could not move further a lot).

Comment: Sorry, yeah, that was just the first part. Then show that $\alpha=f(1)$ :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just a side question. Does what I was writing down make sense in some way (even if incredibly cumbersome), or it is just plain wrong? Those side-feedbacks are actually quite important for me, being self-thaught. Again, thanks a lot.

Comment: No, what you wrote was confused. Again, you never said what $\epsilon$ was, so without that, you were lost. It was deeply unclear what step (3) meant, but it looks like a common type of error about $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs. In particular, $\epsilon-\delta$ proofs are rarely used with constants ($0,x_0$ in this case) unless you are trying to prove something does not converge.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both the explanations.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(1)=f(r\frac{1}{r})=rf(\frac{1}{r})$ where $r\in\mathbb{Z}$ thus $f(\frac{1}{r})=\frac{1}{r}f(1)$ use this and show that $f(x)=f(x.1)=xf(1)$ for rati0nal number then use density of ratinal number in $\mathbb{R}$ and continuty of $f$